# Eclipse PyDev Plug-in Template (PDE)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, eclipse-pde

I just developed a C++ Project Template with CDT and PDE.
So I just enter the Package Name and a Class name and Eclipse creates everything.
Now I want to make the same for PyDev but I don't know really how..
For CDT there was an Extension org.eclipse.cdt.core.TEMPLATES.
For PyDev I haven't found anything like that..

I really kindly ask you if you have any help or can tell me where to look.
I tried for many many hours..

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are templates in PyDev for new modules:

See:
https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev/plugin.xml#L2417 as an example of usage.

But its scope is a single file not a project.

-- you can create a new one in the preferences at `PyDev > editor > templates` (set the context to `New Module` so that it's shown when you create a module).

Comment: Tanks Fabio, for you answer! My Problem still exists, but maybe i have to figure out how to work around. :)